# QEMU isn't able to find the a bootable device

Tags: c, assembly, x86, linker, operating-system

So i started writing my own simple OS but I already failed writing the bootloader xD. I wrote multiple linker.ld files and Makefile to build the project.

running make to build the project works:

```
$ make
--> Compiled:  boot.asm
i686-elf-ld: warning: /Users/fabboy/CLionProjects/os/build/boot.bin has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
--> Created:  boot.bin
--> Compiled:  Entry.c
--> Created:  kernel.bin
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes transferred in 0.014243 secs (103528751 bytes/sec)
17+1 records in
17+1 records out
8708 bytes transferred in 0.000143 secs (60895105 bytes/sec)
10+1 records in
10+1 records out
5448 bytes transferred in 0.000111 secs (49081081 bytes/sec)
```

And then the output looks like this:

```
$ tree
├── build
│   ├── boot.bin
│   ├── bootloader
│   │   └── boot.obj
│   ├── kernel
│   │   └── c
│   │       └── Entry.obj
│   ├── kernel.bin
│   ├── kernel.map
│   └── os_image.img
```

Then I use `make run` to run the QEMU emulator to emulate to OS but the OS doesn't load I only get the message that no Bootable device was found.

[QEMU output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eQoe.png)

I'm running all this on a Macos pc running on a Intel CPU.

Here is the complete project on [Github](https://github.com/Fabbboy/AlpineOS/tree/master)

Thank you very much

Comment: Non-bootable disk in BIOS = last two bytes of MBR are not 55 AA. So what's wrong with boot.bin? `8708 bytes transferred` ... hmm, you should probably check that one (that should have been 512).

Comment: Since your bootloader is a single nasm file, what's the point of using a linker at all?  Your link step produces an ELF file instead of a flat binary, that won't work. Also, you have the signature in the file already, why try to add it from the linker script as well?

Comment: I changed the MBR to `dw 0AA55h` this worked. But this problem with the size i don't know how i should fix this. By changing the Linker.ld I got it down to 788 but still to big I don't know where this is comming from

Comment: You want a flat binary. You don't need a linker. Use `-f bin`. Your boot sector makes no sense, I hope you know that. None of the `init` functions do anything useful, you set `esp` to `0x90000` which will put stack at `0x0000` since you are in real mode, you don't initialize any segment registers, and you don't load the kernel at all before jumping to it.